# gateway timeout error while sending api request through postman

Tags: postman

When I generate token, the token is generated successfully with status 200 OK as shown in the screenshot but When I try to use that token  to send request, I am getting 504 gateway timeout error.

I tried clearing cache but it didn't work.

[image]